# form validation with simple_form and html5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, validation, simple-form

The easy way from our page is
welcome-controller add an email -> second_controller create an new object with the E-Mailadddress.

we have a welcome-controller that shows our welcome-page. At this page you can type an e-mailaddress which will give to an other controller. We work with simple_form
If we that this `config.browser_validations = false` and enter an "normal" text we get an error on the create action. In the older version, without simple_form we get an validation-error.
If we enable this we get the html5 validation. but when the browser doesn't support html5?
Our model is here

```
validates :owner_email,   
        :presence => true,
        :format => { :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/ },
        :on => :create
```

Our welcome-view is here

```
<p>
<h2>Create a list without registration.</h2>
<%= simple_form_for([@list], :html => {:class => 'well' }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :owner_email,  :label => false, :placeholder => 'Your Email.' %>
      <%= f.button :submit, "Create", :class => "btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</p>
```

Our create-action from the second controller is this

```
def create
# create a new list and fill it up
# with some default values
  @list = List.new(
    :title => "List", 
    :description => "Beschreibung",
    :owner_email => "test@domain.com",
    :admin_key => generate_admin_key)
  @list.update_attributes(params[:list])
  respond_with(@list) do |format| 
    format.html {#
      redirect_to :action => "admin", :id => @list.access_key, :status => 301}
  end 
end
```

What have we to change that we get errormessages in the html4 version? can everyone help us please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a :message parameter. Unless you changed simple_form configuration, message errors should be shown on the right side of the field with errors.

```
validates :owner_email,   
        :presence => true,
        :format => { :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/ ,
                     :message => 'Invalid e-mail! Please provide a valid e-mail address'},
        :on => :create
```

Comment: `Unknown validator: 'MessageValidator'`

Thanks, but now i get an Message validation Error on the welcome page. Have i to change the view?

Comment: The :message - block is required in the :format .block
`:format => { :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/, :message => 'Invalid e-mail! Please provide a valid e-mail address' },`